# How to launch the javafx app from java code

Tags: java, javafx

From my java class, I used  the

```
Chart.main(args)
```

to start my javafx class with arguments. 
The problem that the program is blocked in javafx class and cannot return to my java class.

With

```
Chart.launch(args);
```

I get ERROR:

> java.lang.runtimeException: Error: class Image is not a `subclass` of `javafx.application.Application`.

I have found similar example to start `javafx` from `java` but without arguments.

```
javafx.application.Application.launch(Chart.class);
```

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example, your java code would be:

```
public class FXLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FXApplication application = new FXApplication();
        application.handleArgs(args);
        new Thread(application ).start();
    }
}
```

and your JavaFx application would be the following:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXApplication extends Application implements Runnable  {

    public void handleArgs(String[] args){
        // handle java args
        System.out.println(args);
    }        

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // your javafx code
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        launch();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Well, you can use `args` inside the method, but if you save them to a field an try to access them from the `start` method, you'll notice that the application instance started by `launch` is a different one than the one you invoke `handleArgs` for. Also creating a thread here is unnecessary since there is no code on the main thread after `Thread.start`.

Answer (score 3):

The [`launch()` method taking a `Class` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) also takes a list of arguments, so you can do

```
Application.launch(Chart.class, args);
```

Note though that it is the `launch()` method that blocks until the JavaFX application exits. So, depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you might need to call this from a background thread, e.g.

```
new Thread(() -> Application.launch(Chart.class, args)).start();
```

Comment: Thank you James, same Problem: The program is blocked in javafx class and cannot return to my java class. With Javafx I have only drawn and saved a point chart as Image(PNG). It is possible to call my Javafx class Chart from a background thread?How can I do that? Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just invoke the same thing in another thread. I added the simplest example. But since I have no idea why you are wanting to do things like this instead of using the usual startup mechanism, I don't know if that will do what you want. I don't really recommend using threads unless you really understand what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean with "the usual startup mechanism".

Comment: Usually, the `Application` subclass you write (`Chart` here I think) is the starting point for the application. The `start()` method is the entry point and just does the startup work. You seem to have a different class as the startup for the application, and the `Application` subclass serving some other (what?) purpose.